# Inserting timestamp into date field(Oracle)

Tags: oracle, date

We have tables with date fields(type date)  and inserting timestamp into the date field works in some of our oracle environments(We have multiple environments for development)  and fails in some environment.

I would like to know why it works in some cases and some cases it fails with ORA-01843: not a valid month

Example

```
Table1
date1  DATE
```

The following sql works in some environment and fails in some environments

```
Insert into Table1 (date1) values ( to_timestamp(sysdate))
```

Oracle version - Oracle Database 11g

Can we insert timestamp into date field(like above)?  Does oracle supports inserting timestamp values to date field?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `sysdate`, use [`current_timestamp`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions037.htm) (although it is pointless, since it will become a `date` in the database anyway):

```
insert into Table1 (date1) values (current_timestamp)
```

I guess the reason it fails is that `to_timestamp` needs a `varchar` and the conversion failed.

Comment: Can we insert timestamp into date field. Does oracle supports inserting timestamp values to date field?

Comment: Yes, it will become a `date` though because it is implicitly converted.

Comment: Not sure why to_timestamp(sysdate) worked in some of our environments, eventhough to_timestamp needs varchar as you mentioned.

Comment: I guess it should never work, but maybe someone else can shed some light on that.

Comment: Sounds like an implicit casting.

Comment: On the 10g SQL reference manual, http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements002.htm, they do have a matrix which shows it can be done.

Comment: As per the Matrix, DATETIME/ INTERVAL to VARCHAR2 is implicit, which means to_timestamp(sysdate) should have worked.is that right?

Comment: @user3053015: yes. That is what it says.

Comment: ok thank you, if that is the case, it may be related to some database settings which caused the script to fail in some of our environments. The error we got is ORA-01843: not a valid month

Comment: I can't reproduce it so can't say for sure, but it does look so.

Comment: @user3053015: no problem. If there is anything else, please let me know. If not, please don't forget to accept the answer you liked best (also on previous questions).